# Try and catch NotOLE2FileException

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

I wrote this code to determine if the file that the use chose a excel file is. It does work but in the output it always throw a exception. What is the right way to try and catch this exception?

My code:

```
  public class importIntake {
   public importIntake() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{


    JButton open = new JButton();
    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    fc.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("/Users/frank/Desktop/"));
    fc.setDialogTitle("Choose");
    fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);

    if(fc.showOpenDialog(open) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
    }
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(fc.getSelectedFile().toString()));

    String filename = fc.getSelectedFile().toString();
    if(!FilenameUtils.isExtension(filename,"xls")){
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Choose an excel file!");
    }


    HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
    //een sheet object
    HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

    FormulaEvaluator forlulaEvaluator = wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();

    intakestatus IntakeStatuk = new intakestatus();

    Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

    while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
        Row row = rowIterator.next();

        String intaker = row.getCell(17).getStringCellValue();
        String intakeDatum = row.getCell(18).getStringCellValue();
        String start = row.getCell(19).getStringCellValue();
        String herintake = row.getCell(20).getStringCellValue();
        String stopzetting = row.getCell(21).getStringCellValue();
        String verwijzersdoor = row.getCell(22).getStringCellValue();
        String vdcontactpersoon = row.getCell(23).getStringCellValue();
        String vncontactpersoon = row.getCell(26).getStringCellValue();
        String vnemail = row.getCell(28).getStringCellValue();

        String[] intakers = intaker.split(" ");
        String[] intakedatum = intakeDatum.split(" ");
        String[] startDatum = start.split(" ");
        String[] herIntake = herintake.split(" ");
        String[] stopZetting = stopzetting.split(" ");
        String[] verwijzersDoor = verwijzersdoor.split(" ");
        String[] vdContactpersoon = vdcontactpersoon.split(" ");
        String[] vnContactpersoon = vncontactpersoon.split(" ");
        String[] vnEmail = vnemail.split(" ");

        for(int i = 0; i < intakers.length; i++){

            String intakerSplit = intakers[i];
            String intakeDSplit = intakedatum[i];
            String startDatumF = startDatum[i];
            String herIntakeF = herIntake[i];
            String stopZettingF = stopZetting[i];
            String verwijzersDoorF = verwijzersDoor[i];
            String vdContactpersoonF = vdContactpersoon[i];
            String vnContactpersoonF = vnContactpersoon[i];
            String vnEmailF = vnEmail[i];

            IntakeStatuk.setData(intakerSplit,intakeDSplit, startDatumF, herIntakeF, stopZettingF, verwijzersDoorF, 
                    vdContactpersoonF, vnContactpersoonF, vnEmailF);

            boolean result = intakestatusData.insert(IntakeStatuk);

            if(result){
                System.out.println("Work");
            }else{
                System.err.println("Something wrong");
            }
      }

    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Works");
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

The exception thrown is: org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NotOLE2FileException: Invalid header signature; read 0x302E312D46445025, expected 0xE11AB1A1E011CFD0 - Your file appears not to be a valid OLE2 document. I have also updated the code with the apache code i use.

Comment: What Exception is thrown? Where is it thrown (in which line of your code)? What should happen if the Exception is thrown?

Comment: That cannot be the complete code. `NotOLE2FileException` is a Apache POI exception, but there's no POI code visible.

Comment: Additionally: What is the exception *message*?

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: if you type 0x302E312D46445025 reverse in a hex editor, you'll get "%PDF-1.0" ... I'd use WorkbookFactory.create(InputStream) and catch InvalidFormatException instead, i.e. rebase your code from HSSF to the SS Common interface, so you don't need to take care if you process old OLE2 or newer OOXML based files